# How to make tooltip shape use Path?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make tooltip shape use Path ?

expect :
[image]

i try make shape border :

```
class TooltipShapeBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  final double arrowWidth;
  final double arrowHeight;
  final double arrowArc;
  final double radius;

  TooltipShapeBorder({
    this.radius = 0,
    this.arrowWidth = 16.0,
    this.arrowHeight = 8.0,
    this.arrowArc = 0.0,
  }) : assert(arrowArc <= 1.0 && arrowArc >= 0.0);

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.only(bottom: arrowHeight);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) =>
      null ?? Path();

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    rect = Rect.fromPoints(
        rect.topLeft, rect.bottomRight - Offset(0, arrowHeight));
    double x = arrowWidth, y = arrowHeight, r = 1 - arrowArc;
    return Path()
      ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(radius)))
      ..moveTo(rect.topRight.dx - 30, rect.topRight.dy)
      ..relativeLineTo(-x / 2 * r, -y * r)
      ..relativeQuadraticBezierTo(
          -x / 2 * (1 - r), y * (1 - r), -x * (1 - r), 0)
      ..relativeLineTo(-x / 2 * r, y * r);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}
```

and after many tries here is my shot

actual : [image]

could you help me to fix some problem on this design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the fixed shape border. I just added `-` to `y1` of `relativeQuadraticBezierTo`. [Paths in Flutter: A Visual Guide](https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0) will be helpful.

[image]

```dart
class TooltipShapeBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  final double arrowWidth;
  final double arrowHeight;
  final double arrowArc;
  final double radius;

  TooltipShapeBorder({
    this.radius = 0,
    this.arrowWidth = 16.0,
    this.arrowHeight = 8.0,
    this.arrowArc = 0.0,
  }) : assert(arrowArc <= 1.0 && arrowArc >= 0.0);

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.only(bottom: arrowHeight);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) =>
      null ?? Path();

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    rect = Rect.fromPoints(
        rect.topLeft, rect.bottomRight - Offset(0, arrowHeight));
    double x = arrowWidth, y = arrowHeight, r = 1 - arrowArc;
    return Path()
      ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(radius)))
      ..moveTo(rect.topRight.dx - 30, rect.topRight.dy)
      ..relativeLineTo(-x / 2 * r, -y * r)
      ..relativeQuadraticBezierTo(
          -x / 2 * (1 - r), -y * (1 - r), -x * (1 - r), 0)
      ..relativeLineTo(-x / 2 * r, y * r);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}
```